# String format issue affecting validation

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my python script, I am checking the log file and get particular line content as:
`abc-xyz: Attach Complete is about to be sent for jk 2`

Then I validate whether this string matches with my input string value:
`sub_str1 = "abc-xyz: Attach Complete is about to be sent for jk 2"`

**Observation1:**
The actual length of the string is 53. However, when I get the output from the log, it is showing the length as 75. I have also tried `rstrip()`,  `.str()` but nothing worked.
Also, I noticed that the below words alone displaying in red color. Remaining words are showing in normal white color in the ubuntu terminal.
**`abc-xyz: Attach Complete is`**

**Observation2:**

```
print(Cmd_Out1a[0:-1])
print(Cmd_Out1a[5:-1])
print(Cmd_Out1a + "hi")
```

output of observation2:

```
abc-xyz: Attach Complete is about to be sent for jk
abc-xyz: Attach Complete is about to be sent for jk
abc-xyz: Attach Complete is about to be sent for jk 2hi
```

When I validate if `Cmd_Out1a == sub_str1`, it always returns `False` in the program.
Why it is showing different length and how to validate if `substr1 == Cmd_Out1a` for this kind of problem?

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import pexpect
import time     

def Login_Server(hostip,user,passwd):
  User_Info_out = []
  Cmd_Out = ' '
  try:
    Cmd = pxssh.pxssh()
    Cmd.login(hostip, user, passwd)
    Cmd_Out = Execute_Script4(Cmd)
 
  except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    User_Info_out = 'None'
  return User_Info_out,Cmd_Out
 
def Execute_Script4(Cmd):
    Cmd_Out1a,Cmd_Out_str1,Cmd_Out1b = " ", " ", " "
    sub_str1 = "abc-xyz: Attach Complete is about to be sent for jk 2"
    Cmd.sendline('sudo su')
    Cmd.prompt()
 
    Cmd.sendline('log command')
    time.sleep(3)
    Cmd.sendcontrol('c')
    Cmd.prompt()
 
    Cmd_Out1a  = Cmd.before
    Cmd_Out1a = Cmd_Out1a.splitlines()[-3]
    print(Cmd_Out1a)
    print(type(Cmd_Out1a))
    print(len(Cmd_Out1a))
    print(len(sub_str1))

Login_Server('XXX.XXX.X.XX','usera','password')
```

Output:

```
userc@ubuntu:~$ python test1.py

abc-xyz: Attach Complete is about to be sent for jk 2
<type 'str'>
75
53
```

Comment: The code looks like you are using Python 3. Why did you tag Python 2.7?

Comment: Print the `repr()` of this string, so you can see exactly what sort of non-printable characters might be in it.

Comment: Thanks. some non-printable characters are present. '\x1b[32m\x1b[01;31m\x1b[Kabc-xyz: Attach Complete is\x1b[32m\x1b[K about to be sent for jk 2      can you please let me know how to convert this into normal string ?